# Centering iframe + DIV from Bandcamp and Reverbnation

Tags: iframe, html, coding-style, center

[edit 3] - Ok, here's the code, but Chrome and Sea Monkey and Firefox don't display it correctly.  How can I change this?

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Pissing Graffiti - Home</title>
</head>
<body style=" background-color: rgb(102, 102, 102); background-image:
url(&quot;http://static.tumblr.com/iorl8zv/Me9ljgnyz/pgbgtumb.gif&quot;);">
<p></p>
<div style='color: rgb(255, 176, 46)'><b><center>Download the new 8-track SAXAPHONE EP, by Pissing Graffiti</center></b></font></div></div>
<p></p>
<div style="text-align: center;" onClick="document.location='http://music.pissinggraffiti.com';"><IMG SRC="http://static.tumblr.com/iorl8zv/vIXlngmey/cover2.jpg" ALT="Music"></div>
<p></p>
<div><a style='color: rgb(255, 176, 46);' align-text="center;"
href="www.blog.pissinggraffiti.com"><b><center>Head over to the blog.</center></b></a></div>
<p></p>
<div align="center";<img
style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;"
src="http://c.gigcount.com/wildfire/IMP/CXNID=2000002.11NXC/bT*xJmx*PTEzMDkwMTE*OTg1MTYmcHQ9MTMwOTAxMTUwMDU2MSZwPTI3MDgxJmQ9ZmFuX2NvbGxlY3Rvcl9maXJzdF9nZW4mZz*x/Jm9mPTA=.gif"
border="0" height="0" width="0"> <object
classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
height="100" width="434"><param name="movie"
value="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/swf/11/fancollector.swf?page_object_id=artist_470177&amp;backgroundcolor=666666&amp;font_color=FFB02E&amp;posted_by=artist_470177&amp;hide_street_team=true"><param
name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param
name="allowNetworking" value="all"><param
name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="wmode"
value="opaque"> <param name="quality" value="best"><embed
src="http://cache.reverbnation.com/widgets/swf/11/fancollector.swf?page_object_id=artist_470177&amp;backgroundcolor=666666&amp;font_color=FFB02E&amp;posted_by=artist_470177&amp;hide_street_team=true"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
allowscriptaccess="always" allownetworking="all"
allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" quality="best"
height="100" width="434"></object><br>
<img style="visibility:hidden;width:0px;height:0px;"
src="http://www.reverbnation.com/widgets/trk/11/artist_470177/artist_470177/t.gif"
border="0" height="0" width="0"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Forgot to mention the problems.

1 - The Reverbnation @ddy collector isn't showing up

2 - the entire horizontal screen is a hyperlink whereas I just wanted it to be the image.

3 - I just found out that when clicking the link below it tries to send me here: "http://pissinggraffiti.com/www.blog.pissinggraffiti.com" which of course doesn't exist.  "blog.pissinggraffiti.com" works fine however.  I checked my code but can't figure it out. "pissinggraffiti.com goes to my hosted index.html file whereas "blog.pissinggraffiti.com" is a sub-domain that points to my Tumblr page.  What's going on there?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: my bad - I kept replying to Mike, meant to reply here 0.o

Comment: nothing?  Is the format of the @ddy collector bad somehow?  not current?  And what's with adding the href to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your Bandcamp site to be on the left of the Reverbnation collector you'll want to use the [float](http://w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) property with something like this:

```
<iframe style="all-your-other-stuff-that; float: left;">
```

Then as for your link, it's still showing up as blue and underlined because that's the default look and you haven't applied a style to it. The style that you're applying to the surrounding div

```
style="color: rgb(255, 176, 46);"
```

should actually be applied to the link.

```
<a style="color: rgb(255, 176, 46);" href="www.blog.pissinggraffiti.com">Head over to the homepage/blog.</a>
```

Also, if you're going to have that much styling going on, you may want to consider sticking it in a style sheet instead of placing it all inline.

Comment: I've changed my approach and sort of have what I want, but I'm having browser display problems.  Edited post and put up code.  Please help!

Comment: OK - I still haven't figured out problem 1

Answer (score 0):

OK - I still haven't figured out problem 2 but:

1 - had something to do with the code they were giving me.  So I asked them for the html code and just inserted that, adjusted formatting and voila.  All the browsers I have work.  If someone on Windows could test it I would be very thankful!

3 - I had to change the links =/  They were still pinting to the http://pissinggraffiti.com roote and I had to just adjust the image maps/links to have http://blog.pissinggraffiti.com

Thanks guys!

Comment: As for why the whole section is a link instead of the image, it looks like you have your <a> tag outside of that whole section instead of just the <img> tag. So you would want something like <a href="foo"><img src="bar" /></a>

Comment: Mike you are the best.  I don't know why I had it so complicated.  I wish I could give you some sort of rep.  Have a blessed one!